# Batch script that copies all contents of subdirectories into a parent directory?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, batch-processing, command-prompt

Let's say I have a batch file, script.bat. This batch file is placed into a parent folder.

```
> Parent folder
    script.bat
    > subdirectory1
        file1.1
        file1.2
        file1.3
    > subdirectory2
        file2.1
        file2.2
        file2.3
```

How do I write the batch file so that when I double click on it, it copies all the files from (inside the subdirectories) to (the folder that the batch file is located in)?

Comment: `for /d %%I in (*) do copy "%%~I\*" .`

Comment: Thanks, that worked.
Batch noob here, can you explain what each of the components of that command does?

Comment: @rojo, what about posting your solution as an answer? so the OP could accept it (hopefully ;-)) and the question does no longer remain open in the SO database...

Comment: @jameschang Explanation has been moved to an answer at aschipfl's request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're looking for is

```js
for /d %%I in (*) do copy "%%~I\*" .
```

`for` performs the command after `do` on every directory (because of the `/d` switch) matched by `*`. `copy` copies. `%%~I` is a variable with a value of whatever directory name to which the `for` loop has progressed. The tilde in `%%~I` strips surrounding quotation marks, if any. The `.` at the end is shorthand for the current working directory (the directory containing the batch script). See `for /?` in a cmd console for more info.